# Showing a function isn't injective

Tags: functions

I have to show that a composite function $g\circ h$ isn't injective, where:

$g:\Bbb R^2 \times \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2 \times \Bbb R^2 $ where $g(x,y)=(x+y, 3x-y)$

$h:\Bbb R^+ \times \Bbb R^+ \to \Bbb R^+ \times \Bbb R^+ $ where $h(x,y)=(2x+y, xy)$

I have proven that $g$ is injective, so I'm assuming all I have to show is that $h$ isn't.
Is there a shortcut I'm missing to show that $h$ isn't injective?  Is there an easy counter example that I'm potentially missing?

Comment: is that $g.h$ or $g(h)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $h(0, 1) = h(0.5, 0)$ Therefore $g(h(0, 1)) = g(h(0.5, 1))$ and $g \circ h$ is **not** injective.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to see that for each 2-tuple $(z_1,0)$ from the image of h it need to hold
$$2x+y = z_1 \iff y = z_1 - 2x$$
$$xy = 0 = x(z_1-2x)$$

but a product is 0 iff one factor is zero, so you easy get two solutions for $$h(x,y) = (z_1,0)$$